# Embedding MediaWiki pages into main website

Tags: html, node.js, mediawiki

I'm looking for a way to get media wiki articles/pages into my main website. Our "documentation" is all on a separate website using MediaWiki, we want to embed the pages into our current website's template so it looks like it's apart of our website, as much as possible.

This means not having the navigation, headers & footers, etc. that normally come with a MediaWiki website. As well as possibly skinning it to look like the main site.

It might be worth mentioning the main website is running on Node.js

Comment: Are you look at `nodemw`package? [ https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemw#creating-a-bot-instance ]

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a template on your main site. Within the content area of this template you can use the [jQuery load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) to load the content part (`#mw-content-text`) of the MediaWiki page.

The code would look like this:

```
<div id="some-id"></div>
<script>
    $('#some-id').load('URL-to-your-MediaWiki-page #mw-content-text');
</script>
```

Comment: And why not use the api to get "just the content part"? Or, if you really want to use .load() you maybe want to use the render action (url.com/wiki/Article?action=render) to get the page without skin, if you don't want to use the skin html.

Comment: @Florian: I didn't know `?action=render`. Thanks for letting us know!
How would you do that with the API?

Comment: Run a get request to the api endpoint, like: `api.php?page=Albert Einstein&action=parse&format=json` (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?page=Albert%20Einstein&action=parse)